# How to pass array to formdata and save as array in react.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, form-data

i am passing an array to formdata but getting it as string.
How can i save it in array only.

```
tags=["abc", "def", "ghi"]
formData.set("tags",tags);
```

if i do this at frontend then nothing is getting save at backend

```
const clickSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setValues({ ...values, error: "", loading: true });
    tags.forEach((tag) => formData.append("tags[]", tag));
    createProduct(formData).then((data) => {
      if (data.error) {
        setValues({ ...values, error: data.error });
      } else {
        setValues({
          ...values,
          name: "",
          description: "",
        });
      }
    });
  };
```

the backend code after submitting form

```
exports.create = (req, res) => {
  console.log("REQ", req.body);
  let form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.keepExtensions = true;
  form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: "Image could not be uploaded",
      });
    }
    let product = new Product(fields);
    console.log("P", product);

    if (files.photo) {
      product.photo.data = fs.readFileSync(files.photo.path);
      product.photo.contentType = files.photo.type;
    }

    product.save((err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          error: errorHandler(err),
        });
      }
      res.json(result);
    });
  });
};
```

also the req.body giving empty object,why so i have use

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Comment: You cannot set an array value in formData. Read the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append#append_parameters).

Answer (score 4):

this is not how we pass an array to formData.
you have to loop through all the array items and add them to formData one by one.

```
const frmData = new FormData();
const tags = ["abc", "def", "ghi"];
tags.forEach(tag => frmData.append('tags[]', tag))
```

So the takeaway here is that when you want to add an array to form data you have to use key name as "key[]" with the array symbol at the end.

Comment: Doing this no data gets added in the form data

Comment: try seeing the formData using frmData.getAll('tags[]')

Comment: It's showing all but nothing is passed while saving the data in DB

Comment: then there must be something wrong with the backend

Comment: I have added the backend above, please check